# sort SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a List/Library and I would like to sort this list/library in such a way that some items are always on the top of the list despite the number of items added to the list. Can anyone provide me an Out of the Box solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done by sorting on metadata

1) Create another column as orderno, assign the numbers only to the items that you always wanted on the top of the list.
2) go to library/list settings, under view All documents, first sort by orderno and then if you want  recent items after that fixed items, second sort by created/modified desc

Comment: Apart from the second sort, your reply was really helpful